# Dockerfile: How to run a linux command and save its output in variable

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I need to pass the `wlan0` ip address as environment variable in `Dockerfile`. As this on `DHCP` so the IP address changes some time. I thought of running the below command to get the ip address and then use it in Dockerfile:

`ip -4 addr show wlan0 | grep -oP '(?<=inet\s)\d+(\.\d+){3}'`

Above commands gives me `192.168.1.125`. I want to use this ip address to pass it as environment variable. For this, I used:

```
RUN wlan="$(ip -4 addr show wlan0 | grep -oP '(?<=inet\s)\d+(\.\d+){3}')" && echo $wlan

ENV HOST_WLAN0=$wlan
```

But it gave me an error `Device "wlan0" does not exist.`. How can I resolve this.?

Comment: the run command is executed inside the container you are configuring. but i guess wlan0 belongs to the docker host system. I would also guess that you have an issue in the design of your planned solution. the docker container should not know such infrastructur details from the host system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting this error because when building the image, the command executed is being "isolated" from the host and runs in a separate namespaced layer.

What you need to do is pass the ip address as a build arg.

**Dockerfile**:

```
...
ARG wlan
ENV HOST_WLAN0=$wlan
```

**Build command:**

```
docker build --build-arg wlan=$(ip -4 addr show wlan0 | grep -oP '(?<=inet\s)\d+(\.\d+){3}') ...
```

This will input the correct IP address into the Docker build.

Comment: While building it says `unknown flag: --build-args`

Comment: Fixed there was a typo.

Comment: Okay so I have found an issue with this too. When we run the build command giving the build arguments, it runs sucessfully. Then I start its container with the flag `--restart=always` becaus I want it to be restarted always. But when the ip address changes as it is on DHCP, it still shows the older one. To make  it use new IP address, I had to run the build command again.

Comment: In that case pass it as an env variable to the run command: `docker run -e HOST_WLAN0=$(ip -4 addr show wlan0 | grep -oP '(?<=inet\s)\d+(\.\d+){3}') ..`

Comment: Okay if I am doing this then I will have to remove `ARG wlan` & `ENV HOST_WLAN0=$wlan` from the dockerfile.?

Comment: They will be useless unless you need them inside the Dockerfile when executing some other command.  So yes you can remove them.

Comment: No it still shows older ip. When the host boots again, it takes some other ip. Container is started automatically as `--restart always` flag is used so it shows loder ip.

Answer (score 0):

The command (ip -4 addr show wlan0 | grep -oP '(?<=inet\s)\d+(.\d+){3}') which provides output is running in Host machine thats why you are getting output of it.

When you try to run the same command through Dockerfile, It will create temporary container start running the RUN command and there it wont find wlan0 device. Because of this reason you are getting the error "device "wlan0" does not exist."

I have a suggestion

To overcome your problem create a cron job in host machine which it updates IPaddress automatically into the file and place it in Volume. Share the volume with the container and access this file from container and use it in your application

Comment: Your suggestion is great. I will try it